# Work out percentage correct/wrong over 2 fields in Mysql in single query

Tags: mysql

In a single MySQL query, how can I workout the percentage / score achieved on a test based on the following output. Answer given is test_answer_id and correct answer is correct_answer_id.
In the below example, 3 were scored wrong so should return 70%

```
id      doctor_id   test_id test_question_id    test_answer_id  correct_test_answer_id
168836  862         123     2706                3353            3353
168837  862         123     2707                3354            3354
168838  862         123     2708                3357            3357
168839  862         123     2709                3358            3359
168840  862         123     2710                3360            3360
168841  862         123     2711                3363            3363
168842  862         123     2712                3365            3365
168843  862         123     2713                3367            3366
168844  862         123     2714                3369            3369
168845  862         123     2715                3370            3371
```

Comment: What's the structure of the tables you're using? What's the query you tried and is throwing an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query. You just divide number of correct answers on total count of questions:

```
select doctor_id,
       test_id,
       sum(case when test_answer_id = correct_test_answer_id 
           then 1 else 0 end) * 100.0 / count(*) 
from table
group by doctor_id, test_id
```